# HBASE: Get All columns of specific Column Family

Tags: python, hbase

I created this table in Hbase with 2 Column Family:

```
connection.create_table(
    'twitter_db',
    {'Hashtag': dict(),
     'Lang': dict(),
   }
)
```

How can I get all the columns in the Column Family 'Hashtag' of a row key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using happybase, you can use following:

```
row = table.row('row-key', columns=['cf1'])
```

It will give you all the columns and value for column family "cf1" for "row-key".

More documentation is available here: